# Filter Media by Featured on Admin

Tags: filters, media, media-library, sort

Usually we can filter images in Media > Library by:

- date
- by MIME type,
- and by attached/unattached files

...but I'd like to expand this to a filter by Featured images. This way, we could filter only those images that are set to be Featured of some Post or Custom Post Type.

Do you have some ideas to make it possible?

Thanks,

**EDIT**

I've added this code in functions.php as per [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116069/complex-restriction-of-items-in-media-library) (it won't filter, but it should restrict the results in the Media Library to those images that are Featured, that is, that have _thumbnail_id as meta), but the admin won't load and the server will drop an error.

```
add_action ('pre_get_posts', 'restrict_media') ;
function
restrict_media ($query)
{

    // get posts with thumbnails
    $args = array (
        'post_type' => 'galleries',
        'post_status' => array ('publish'),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array (
            array (
                'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                ),
            ),
        ) ;
    $with_thumbnail = new WP_Query ($args) ;
    // get the IDs of the thumbnails
    $thumbnail_ids = array_map (function ($p) { return (get_post_meta ($p->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true)) ; },
        $with_thumbnail->posts) ;

    // include all thumbnails
    $query->set ('post__in', array($thumbnail_ids)) ;

    return ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can add the *Featured* option as a *fake* mime-type with:

```
add_filter( 'media_view_settings', function( $settings )
{
    $settings['mimeTypes']['wpsefeaturedimage'] = 'Featured';
    return $settings;
});
```

It will show up like this:

[image: Featured option]

Then we can use the `posts_where` filter and check for our fake mime type:

```
/**
 * Filter for featured images in the media library popup
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q )
{
    if( 'wpsefeaturedimage' === $q->get( 'post_mime_type' ) )
    {
        // Remove the fake mime type
        $q->set( 'post_mime_type', '' );
        // Mark this query as featured filtered
        $q->set( 'wpse_filter_featured', true );

        add_filter( 'posts_where', function ( $where, \WP_Query $q )
        {
            if( $q->get( 'wpse_filter_featured' ) )
            {
                global $wpdb;
                // Add 'featured images' restriction to the SQL query
                $where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN 
                    ( SELECT DISTINCT m.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} m 
                      WHERE m.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
                    ) ";
            }
            return $where;
        }, 10, 2 );
    }
}, 1 );
```

We can probably adjust this further.